# SoapClient gettting Notice: Array to string conversion and

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

**I have written this code and getting error**

Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/content/09/13963009/html/coupon/api/dgmwsdl1.php on line 12

Error : Internal Server Error

```
<?php   
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://webservices.dgperform.com/dgmpublisherwebservices.cfc?wsdl');
echo '<pre>';
// shows the methods coming from the service 
print_r($soapClient->__getFunctions());
print_r($soapClient->__getTypes());
$params = array('Dg-Affiliate-Id'   => 'xxxx','Dg-Affiliate-Token'  => 'xxxx','fromDate'  => '2015-01-31','toDate'  => '2016-03-04');
//  $params = array('username'  => 'xxxx','password'    => 'xxxx','fromDate'  => '2015-01-31','toDate'  => '2016-03-04');
try {
$auth_call=$soapClient->GetSales($params);
//          $auth_call=$soapClient->__soapCall("GetSales", $params);
print_r($auth_call);
die();      
} 
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
die('Error : ' . $fault->faultstring);
}
?>
```

**2nd script with different call**

```
<?php   
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://webservices.dgperform.com/dgmpublisherwebservices.cfc?wsdl');
echo '<pre>';
// shows the methods coming from the service 
print_r($soapClient->__getFunctions());
print_r($soapClient->__getTypes());
$params = array('Dg-Affiliate-Id'   => 'xxxx','Dg-Affiliate-Token'  => 'xxxx','fromDate'  => '2015-01-31','toDate'  => '2016-03-04');
//  $params = array('username'  => 'xxxx','password'    => 'xxxx','fromDate'  => '2015-01-31','toDate'  => '2016-03-04');
try {
//$auth_call=$soapClient->GetSales($params);
$auth_call=$soapClient->__soapCall("GetSales", $params);
print_r($auth_call);
die();      
} 
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
die('Error : ' . $fault->faultstring);
}
?>
```

Error : Internal Server Error

For live script you can refer http://vtechvision.com/coupon/api/dgmwsdl1.php and http://vtechvision.com/coupon/api/dgmwsdl2.php

Answer (score 0):

I can explain why you get `Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/content/09/13963009/html/coupon/api/dgmwsdl1.php on line 12` at the first case:

While you print `$soapClient->GetSales($params);` you need to pass params as described at WSDL

```
GetSales(string $username, string $password, double $campaignid, string $saleStatus, string $dateFilterType, string $fromDate, string $toDate, double $optionalParams, double $sku)
```

But next returned string `Internal Server Error` is just response of `wsdl:service name="dgmpublisherwebservicesService"`